# How do I control which power plans are "preferred" and which are "additional"?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

In `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options`, some power plans are "preferred" and some are "additional". I want to make an "additional" plan into a "preferred" plan. How can I do this?

Comment: I do not think you are going to be able to get a third power plan to display as a preferred plan.  I use a batch file to change my power settings.  `:minpower
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-AC 1
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-AC 2
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 3
exit /b` `:normalpower 
POWERCFG /CHANGE /MONITOR-TIMEOUT-AC 10
POWERCFG /CHANGE /DISK-TIMEOUT-AC 29
POWERCFG /CHANGE /STANDBY-TIMEOUT-AC 30
exit /b`Do you want to write a batch file?  You will create shortcuts on your desktop to apply the power settings you want.

Comment: Yeah I can use powercfg.exe. So "preferred plans" are always two, chosen by windows according to some system that I still can't figure out?

Comment: If you figure out a way let me know.  I change three settings alot: when the disk turns off, when the display turns off, and when to sleep.  [powercfg /change](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options) and a batch file could not make it any easier.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10, go to Control Panel, Power Options, and select Create a Power Plan (left side). Make a new plan to fit your circumstances. Once saved, make it your default plan.

If you want to change the order of the plans, give your plan an A name to move it up or else delete the other plans. I always delete Airplane mode to prevent it from taking over.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run POWERCFG /LIST to see the list. 
Then powercfg ? to see help and then powercfg /delete "GUID of the plan to delete"

For a very long time, I have just used Balanced and adjusted it to fit me. That works as well.

Comment: As written, this doesn't explain how to make a power plan **preferred**.